# Change background color of specific Gnome nautilus bookmark in the left side bar

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gnome-shell

I have added some bookmarks in the left sidebar of nautilus on Ubuntu 20.04 to ease access.

Not all bookmarks are equally important to me, so I would like to highlight some by changing the background color to yellow, so that I can instantly see the most important ones.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in nautilus. It would be a valid feature request, though.